# How to persistently set MySQL (Linux mysql command) session time zone to UTC?

Tags: mysql, linux, timezone, client

I'm using MySQL on Linux (CentOS, recent release).  I want the MySQL system variable `time_zone` to reflect UTC.

When I start a MySQL session (using the command-line tool `mysql`) and check the time zone setting, I see this:

```
mysql> select @session.time_zone ;
+--------------------+
| @session.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| NULL               |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I know (see [MySQL Set UTC time as default timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/mysql-set-utc-time-as-default-timestamp)) that I can configure the *server* to have UTC as its default timezone.  What I want is to set up a **client session** to have UTC as the default.

The page above says I can set a MySQL system variable in my SQL syntax, like this:

```
mysql> set @session.time_zone="+0:00";
```

This leads to having the session time zone to be the local (`SYSTEM`) time zone:

```
mysql> show variables like '%zone%' ;
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| system_time_zone | PDT    |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM |
+------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I'd like to do is to set the time zone as a kind of preference for a user, like a setting in `.my.cnf`.

Problem is, the [MySQL 'mysql' command options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html) don't list a 'time zone' option for `.my.cnf`, and (of course I had to try it anyway) putting

```
 time_zone="+0:00"
```

in my `$HOME/.my.cnf` file leads to the message

```
 mysql: unknown variable 'time_zone=+0.00'
```

I tried setting the `TZ` environment variable, and that has no impact.

As the StackExchange reference above says, the only effective way I've found is through issuing the SQL command:

```
mysql> select @session.time_zone ;
+--------------------+
| @session.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| NULL               |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @session.time_zone="+0:00";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @session.time_zone ;
+--------------------+
| @session.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| +0:00              |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**So...**

My question then is, is there some other mechanism for setting MySQL session variables?  Or some other way to set the session time zone?

Comment: The proper way to show the time_zone active in the current session is `SELECT @@time_zone;`. That value is the one defined locally in the session or the one inherited from the server setting.

Answer (score 2):

Use `default_time_zone=UTC` in `my.cnf`.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562456/mysql-setting-time-zone-in-my-cnf-options-file

Comment: You should add which `section` it should live under and which MySQL version you are talking about.

Comment: `my.cnf` is not `~/.my.cnf`.
This question is explicitely about setting the session timezone in a client session. But the answers in the link so far only give solutions by changing a server setting that affects all sessions.

Answer (score 1):

In `~/.my.cnf`:

```
[mysql]
init_command="SET time_zone='+0:00'"
```